# Sending a file between AIR applications using local connection

Tags: apache-flex, air, flashbuilder4

How do i send a text file between air applications using local connection?

Sender AIR

private var conn:LocalConnection;

```
            public function init():void
            {
                conn=new LocalConnection();
                conn.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,onStatus);             
            }

            private function Sender():void {

                var alphabets:File= File.createTempFile();
                var file:FileStream = new FileStream();
                file.open(alphabets,FileMode.WRITE);
                file.writeUTFBytes("Have a nice day");      
                file.close();
                conn.send("app#ReceiverAIR:MyConnection", "lcHandler",t1.text,alphabets);
            }

            private function onStatus(event:StatusEvent):void {
                switch (event.level) {
                    case "status":
                        trace("LocalConnection.send() succeeded");
                        break;
                    case "error":
                        trace("LocalConnection.send() failed");
                        break;
                }
            }           

    ]]>
</fx:Script>



<mx:TextArea id="t1" />
<mx:Button id="b1" label="Send" click="Sender()" />
```

Receiver AIR

import flash.net.LocalConnection;

```
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var conn:LocalConnection;

        public function LocalConnectionReceiverExample()     {

            conn = new LocalConnection();
            conn.client = this;
            try {
                conn.allowDomain('app#SenderAIR');
                conn.connect("MyConnection");

            } catch (error:ArgumentError) {
                trace("Can't connect...the connection name is already being used by another SWF");
            }
        }

        public function lcHandler(msg:String,myfile:File):void {
            trace("i am in lcHandler");
            t1.text=msg;    
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:TextArea id="t1" editable="false"/>
```

It gives the following error

```
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: 
flash.net.LocalConnection was unable to invoke callback lcHandler. 
error=TypeError: Error #1034: 
Type Coercion failed: 
cannot convert Object@83d6791 to flash.filesystem.File.
```

Comment: You'll need to explicitly state which side gives the error.

Comment: The receiver gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u cant send a file this way... i finally created a byte array and sent the byte array to the receiver. Then i copied the byte array to a file at the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to reflect changes from the OP**

Thanks for the update.  From what I understand, all the objects you send through a LocalConnection must meet the following stipulations:

1. They must be serializable using AMF
2. The serialized data must not exceed 40K

I am guessing that File is not a serializable type.

Things to try:

1. Register an alias.  Run `flash.net.registerClassAlias('FileAlias', File)` on both sides
2. Send a more primitive data type.  Send the file name or the file data instead?

Good luck!
Brian